# ASIHTTPRequest - Adding to queue, but i get queueFailed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest. i need to why `requestWentWrong` gets executed ? There are times where the application works fine, but sometimes it executes the `requestWentWrong` method.

1.) I need to know why this is hapenning ?

2.) what should i do when `requestWentWrong` is executed ? SHould i send add another operation to the queue or ?

```
    [[self queue] cancelAllOperations];
    [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self queue] setDelegate:self];
    [[self queue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestCompletedL:)];
    [[self queue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrongL:)];
    setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueCompletedL:)];

    ASIHTTPRequest *req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"]];
    [[self queue] addOperation:req];    
    [[self queue] go];
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can't requeue operations (if I remember it right), You'll have to make a new operation and add it to the queue
- when requestWentWrong is called, look at request.error and/or request.responseStatusCode.. that should help

Comment: How do i make a new operation ? if i call the above code will it OK. Because it cancels items of the queue and add the operation freshly ?

Comment: I get the `responseStatusCode` as `0`. i have no clue how this came. and when i printed the `Headers` as it was `null`